# Makes two folders when only one is requested [Batch]

Tags: batch-file, copy, mkdir

I have made a test worm using batch for educational reasons, but there is a bug in the code somewhere where it creates 2 folders, but it only copies the files into one of them, and they have different folder names too. I have attempted to debug, but after searching, the extra folder gets added externally somehow.

```
::there was a small script to get admin, but i dont think 
::that was important, so i edited it out.

::::::::::::::: PARAMS
if EXIST Worm.bat (
echo test5
)
::Make sure that CD stays CD
set CDS=%cd%
set ver=0.01
set file=%0
set fln=%0.bat
echo test
set fil=%fil%%ver%%random%
set file=%fil%
:::::::::::::: PARAMS
::@echo off
title ~~WinWormSELFxTractor%ver%~~
echo WELCOME TO HELL 
mkdir "%file%"
copy "%CDS%\%fln%" "%file%\Worm.bat"
cd %file%

::copy %0.bat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the double quotes added in the set commands and the tilda modifiers
and the cd command is changed.

Test it to see if it does what you want.

```
::::::::::::::: PARAMS
if EXIST Worm.bat (
echo test5
)
::Make sure that CD stays CD
set "CDS=%cd%"
set "ver=0.01"
set "file=%~0"
set "fln=%~n0.bat"
echo test
set "fil=%fil%%ver%%random%"
set "file=%fil%"
:::::::::::::: PARAMS
::@echo off
title ~~WinWormSELFxTractor%ver%~~
echo WELCOME TO HELL 
mkdir "%file%"
copy "%CDS%\%fln%" "%file%\Worm.bat"
cd /d "%file%"

::copy "%~n0.bat"
```

Comment: I reviewed the thing that made the script get admin, and then i found out that it ran it twice :P  Thanks for the answer though, It made my script better!